# C++ storing std::future form std::async in vector and wating for all

Tags: c++, stdasync, std-future

I want to do several tasks in parallel with std::async and then wait until all the futures have completed.

```
void update() {
  // some code here
}

int main() {

  std::vector<std::future<void>> handles(5);

  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    auto handle = std::async(std::launch::async, &update);
    handles.emplace_back(std::move(handle));
  }

  for (auto& handle : handles) {
    handle.wait();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

But when executing the program i get an `std::future_error` thrown:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::future_error'
  what():  std::future_error: No associated state
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And i wonder why. Shouldnt I be able to store the future objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You initialized your `handles` array with 5 default-constructed elements, then you emplaced 5 more into it. It now has 10 elements, the first 5 of which are default-constructed and therefore not associated with anything to wait for.

Don't create the vector with 5 elements. I think you were trying to *reserve space* for 5 elements - this can be done by calling `reserve` after the vector is constructed.